# Is it possible to temporarily skip media restore in WhatsApp?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore, whatsapp.app

I use WhatsApp on an iPhone X. I have chat history and media backed up on my iCloud. The total size of the backup is around 6 GB.

I had to send in the iPhone X for repair, and I’m using a temporarily loaned iPhone 6.

I restored the WhatsApp chat history from iCloud, but the iPhone 6 is a 16 GB variant. I’m unable to restore the media onto this phone since “system files” are around 11 GB. If I turn off iCloud Drive, it goes down to 7 GB but with that turned off, I can’t backup/restore WhatsApp. The only thing enabled in iCloud Drive is WhatsApp so I don’t know why it’s consuming 4GB on the phone when I haven’t restored media.

Is WhatsApp backup cumulative?

- If I skip the media restore, and continue backing up the chat history, will I be able to restore the entire chat history and media on my iPhone X when I get it back?
- Will the media part of the backup be erased from iCloud if I skip media restore and do a chat history backup on the temporary phone?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that you restore the backup on the iPhone 6. Once restored, it disables the backup of that iPhone 6 so that it does not replace the original copy of the iPhone X. Then when you have your iPhone X again, you will be able to restore the copy original.

On the other hand I recommend that you make a backup in iCloud of all the content and a backup in iTunes.

Comment: Thanks, Raul. Sorry, I don't understand completely. I have restored chat history on iPhone 6 but I'm not able to restore the media due to limited storage capacity on the phone. 

If I skip media restore and take a backup on iPhone 6, will it overwrite the backup on iCloud to reflect the content on the current phone? or will it add on "new content" to the backup on iCloud? I can't risk trying this out and losing all of my old backed up data. 

For the phone, I have taken a full backup on iTunes and will restore to iPhone X when I get it back.

Comment: @VigneshSubramaniam What I want to say is that if you only use another iphone temporarily, you restore Whatspp capias even if you do not have the full copy. Disable backup copies of whatsapp on the temporary iphone because if your temporary iphone makes a backup it will overwrite the one you have on your iPhone. When you stop having the temporary iPhone, you can restore that copy you had before.

Comment: Ok, got it. It would've been nice to have the new content added on to the old backup. I won't back up from the temporary iPhone then. Thanks!